# Работа с несколькими таблицами Excel: выборка по условию

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

Подскажите новичку, через какой модуль в Python можно выполнить следующую процедуру и как?
Обычно я использую pandas и openpyxl, но сейчас не хватает опыта, чтобы составить условие.

Есть две таблицы Excel с одинаковым столбиком "Название лекарств" и по два столбика в каждой таблицы с минимальным и максимальным значением их цены. Необходимо на выходе получить новую таблицу, где мы получим только те лекарства, которые есть в двух аптеках, и диапазон цен во второй аптеке будет укладываться в диапазон первой.

К примеру, названия совпадают, и мин.цена массива 1 < мин.цена массива 2, а макc.цена массива 1> макc.цена массива 2, то включить в новую таблицу всю строку.

Начал так, но это просто мысли, а не код - так как, наверное, и половины нет от необходимых данных...

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import re

df_a1=pd.read_excel(r'C:\apteka_1.xlsx', dtype='str')

df_a2=pd.read_excel(r'C:\apteka_2.xlsx', dtype='str')

if df_a1['Лекарства'] = df_a2['Лекарства']

 if df_a1['min_price_1'] < df_a2['min_price_2']

   if df_a1['max_price_1'] > df_a2['max_price_2']


df.to_excel('itog.xlsx',index=False)
```

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, образец данных. Желательно, в воспроизводимом формате наподобие `df = pd.DataFrame( {'ACCOUNTID': [65.0, 221.0, 242.0, 250.0, 265.0], 'ZONENUMBER': ['ccac', '8ee8', 'a444', 'a77f', 'a77f']} )`

Comment: df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Лекарства': [Терафлю, Колдрекс, Активированный уголь, Мезим Форте], 'min_price': [500,400,10,350],  'max_price': [600,500,20,450]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Лекарства': [Колдрекс, Мезим Форте, Активированный уголь, Терафлю], 'min_price': [420,310,5,550],  'max_price': [440,320,15,560]})   на выходе должен вывести все строки в новую таблицу из df_1 по терафлю и Колдрекс

Answer (score 0):

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Лекарства': ['Терафлю', 'Колдрекс', 'Активированный уголь', 'Мезим Форте'], 'min_price': [500, 400, 10, 350],
     'max_price': [600, 500, 20, 450]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Лекарства': ['Колдрекс', 'Мезим Форте', 'Активированный уголь', 'Терафлю'], 'min_price': [420, 310, 5, 550],
     'max_price': [440, 320, 15, 560]})

df = df_1.merge(df_2, on='Лекарства')
mask = df['min_price_x'].lt(df['min_price_y']) & df['max_price_x'].gt(df['max_price_y'])
res = df_1.loc[mask[mask].index]
print(res)
```

```
  Лекарства  min_price  max_price
0   Терафлю        500        600
1  Колдрекс        400        500
```

Comment: Спасибо!! сейчас попробую